C++ overload resolution problem: How to make vector fill constructor overload instead of vector initializer list construtor?
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<char> v1 = { size_t(0),0 };
    vector<char*> v2 = { size_t(0),0 };

    cout << v1.size() << endl;// 2
    cout << v2.size() << endl;// 0
    return 0;
}

v1 calls initializer list, but v2 calls fill constructor.
I do know explicitly calling fill constructor works.
vector<char> v1 = vector<char>(size_t(0), 0);
vector<char> v1(size_t(0), 0);

But is there a way to make v1 overloads fill constructor, without explicitly calling it (just like how v2 works)?

Interestingly I'm seeing different results: https://godbolt.org/z/W1PdMhr57

@user4581301 That looks like a GCC bug. The list initializer constructor is no viable, because size_t(0) is not a literal 0 and therefore not a null pointer constant that can be implicitly converted to char* for the initializer list constructor. Clang does not behave that way.

If you want a fill constructor, call it vector<char> v1(size_t(0), 0);, There is a bunch of questions here about {a, b} vs. (a, b) for vector constructors.

Either of the two ways you show at the bottom is the correct solution.
There is no semantic difference to your first code snippet, aside from the constructor choice being made. So there shouldn't be any problem with using these syntax constructs.
In terms of constructor choice the curly braces are intended to signify that you want to prefer the interpretation of the arguments as "elements" in some meaning specific to the type, rather than any other interpretation.
In the case of vector<char*> v2 = { size_t(0),0 }; there is however no interpretation of size_t(0) as a char*, because size_t(0) can't be converted to char* implicitly as it is not a null pointer constant like a literal 0 is. Therefore the other interpretation as constructor arguments is chosen.
However, in modern C++, you shouldn't rely on the implicit conversion from 0-valued integral literals to null pointer values as you do with 0 as argument to a char*. Since C++11 there is nullptr for that, which can't have a lot of otherwise surprising interactions. And even before C++11 it was custom to use the NULL macro from C instead of writing literal-0 directly to distinguish intended null pointer constants from integral constants better. The special behavior of 0 literals exists only for backwards-compatibility.
So, if you want to signify that you want a vector to be filled with 0 copies of the second argument, you should never write braces and always write:
vector<char> v1(0, 0);
vector<char*> v2(0, nullptr);

or
auto v1 = vector<char>(0, 0);
auto v2 = vector<char*>(0, nullptr);

If you like you can of course repeat the type name instead of auto as you do. Again, there is no semantic difference.
Also note that I left out the conversion to size_t. It has no effect on the choice of constructor anymore.

So, vector fill constructor cannot be implicit invoked ,but vector<char*> fill constructor can ?vector Initilizer list constructor is prefered over fill constructor if possible ,am I right?

@iouvxz All of the initialization syntax constructs call the constructor implicitly. It is impossible to call constructors explicitly in C++. As I said, either initialization syntax has 100% identical semantics, except for whether the std::initializer_list constructor is preferred over other constructors in overload resolution.
